# want to send welcomemail to new user laravel filament

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have a work management in laravel and filament I want to send mail if new customer registered by admin or by user so how do that I found some tutorial for user side but for admin side I'm not sure how to do that help me to resolve this

Find a method to send mail if a user created by admin in filament dashboard

Comment: I'm not familiar with Filament, but Laravel has [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events) and [Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#creating-jobs) that you can use to trigger emails like this

Comment: Tnx for that but I'm.new to.laravel.now learning can gimme me small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [document](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/creating-records#lifecycle-hooks) said

> There are several available hooks for the Create page:

The one that can help you send email or any other notifications is `afterCreate()`.

Try creating a new Event using:

```
php artisan make:event AdminRegisteredEvent
```

Then create a new Listener using:

```
php artisan make:listener SendWelcomeEmailListener
```

Attach the listener to the event in `EventServiceProvider.php`.

After that call the event in `afterCreate()` method.